# Can't write file using FS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, http, fs

So, I have a NodeJS API using express and I want to get data from a HTTP request and store it in a local JSON file. This is the file that contains the function to write the local file:

```
    const fs = require('fs').promises;
    async function updateData(req,res){
       let { name, phone, email, addres, whatsapp, officeHours} = req.body;
       let configs={
        name:name,
        phone:phone,
        email:email,
        addres:addres,
        whatsapp:whatsapp,
        officeHours: officeHours
      };
       let data = JSON.stringify(configs);
       console.log(data);
       try{
        await fs.writeFile('./configs.json', data);
       }catch(err){
        throw err;
       }
    }
module.exports = {updateData};
```

And this is the part of the code I use to call the function with the Post route

```
routes.post('/storedata', storeData.updateData);
```

When I send the HTTP request, using Insomnia, I don't get any errors and the data is logged in the console, but the file isn't written.

Comment: Try an absolute path like `writeFile( __dirname + '/configs.json', data)`

Comment: BTW you can do `JSON.stringify(req.body)` directly. You are doing just that, with extra steps (destructuring the body, then duplicating everything in a new `configs` object). You can do `let data = JSON.stringify(req.body)` directly

Comment: that worked, thank you so much!

Comment: Ha nice, I have posted it as an answer, so you can mark it as accepted :)

Answer (score 0):

Try an absolute path like `writeFile( __dirname + '/configs.json', data)`